# Bootstrap-ui: Popover inside Container

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

i have the following problem:

I have a container for my header. This container has a fixed size. Then comes my container for the content. This container has the attributes:

```
position=absolute
```

and

```
overflow-y=auto.
```

The problem is:
If I place a popover inside that content, this popover is cut off. If I add the property `append-to-body="true"`, it will shown correctly at this point. But If i scroll, the popover will stay on the same position.

Does anyone has a good solution for that?

My plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MgetwTPofYwQalEDX67u?p=preview